# How to structure Out-File as directory then any files within that directory

Tags: powershell

This is what I've been able to build so far but I get multiple directory listings if there is more than one file in the directory.  I am unsure how to group the output by directory name.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $patchesRemovedPath | 
    ForEach-Object {
        "$($_.Directory.Name)`n    $($_.Name)`n" | 
            Out-File "$patchesRemovedPath\Patches Removed Log.txt" -Append
    }
```

Current output:

```
Folder1
    File1
Folder1
    File2
Folder1
    File3
Folder2
    File1
Folder2
    File2
Folder2
    File3
```

I would like to end up with a .txt file as follows:

```
Folder1
    File1
    File2
    File3
Folder2
    File1
    File2
    File3
```

Comment: I'm not sure how did you get such output? Is Folder1 and Folder2 inside the given path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need 2 loops: one for the directories, the other for the files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\root\folder' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
  "`n{0}" -f $_.Name
  Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File | ForEach-Object {
    '    {0}' -f $_.Name
  }
} | Out-File 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```

For simplicity reasons I'm using PowerShell v3 syntax here. In PowerShell v2 you'll have to use `Where-Object` filters restricting the `Get-ChildItem` results to folders and files respectively.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, that worked great.  The only question I have for you is would it be possible to have an empty line prior to the start of a new directory?

Comment: Sure. Simply echo the directory name like this instead of echoing just the name: ``"`n{0}" -f $_.Name``

Comment: That appears to separates the the files.  What I was looking for was to have an empty space between the last files of a directory and the new directory beneath it.

Comment: In the 2nd line, not the 4th line.

Comment: Never mind.  it was my editor that was messing it up.  You were great!!!  Thanks for the help.